# WiX installer Reference to heat file not found

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, heat

Following [this](http://chriseelmaa.com/harvesting-files-with-wix-heat/) tutorial, I use this command to harvest a folder:

```
heat dir "$(SolutionDir)\scr\A\A.WindowsService\bin\$(Configuration)" -dr ConfigurationUtilityDir -gg -g1 -cg ConfigurationUtilityComponents -out "$(SolutionDir)\scr\Installers\A\AInstaller\ConfigurationUtilityHeat.wxs"
```

The .wxs file is properly generated (called 'ConfigurationUtilityHeat', just for test) and I included it into the sln.
Then, to use it to build the installer, I wrote the following code:

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="AInstallerHeat" Level="1">
  <ComponentRef Id='ConfigurationUtilityComponents' />
</Feature>

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <!-- Program Files (x86) -->
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name='PFiles'>
    <!-- B folder -->
    <Directory Id='BDIR' Name='B'>
      <!-- A folder -->
      <Directory Id="ConfigurationUtilityDir" Name="A">
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

But the build fails with this error:
Unresolved reference to symbol 'Component:ConfigurationUtilityComponents' in section 'Product:*'.

How can I solve?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved changing 'ComponentRef' to 'ComponentGroupRef' in 'Feature' node